# R: DALEX explain Fails to Read In Target Variable Data

Tags: r

I'm running a simple lm model in R and I am trying to analyze the results using the DALEX package explain object.

My model is as follows: `lm_model <- lm (DV ~ x + z, data = datax)`

If it matters, x and z are factors and DV is numeric. The lm runs with no errors, and everything looks fine via summary(lm_model).

When I try to create the explain object in DALEX like so:

```
lm_exp <- DALEX::explain(lm_model, label = "lm", data = datax, y = datax$DV)
```

It gives me the following:

```
Preparation of a new explainer is initiated     
  -> model label       :  lm 
  -> data              :  15375  rows  49  cols 
  -> data              :  tibbble converted into a data.frame 
  -> target variable   :  15375  values 

Error in if (is_y_in_data(data, y)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Before the lm is run, datax is filtered for values between .2 and 1 using the subset command. Looking at summary(datax$DV) and sum(is.na(datax$DV)), everything looks fine. I also checked for blanks / errors using a filter in Excel. For those reasons, I do not believe there are any blanks in the DV col of datax, so I am unsure of why I am receiving "Error in if (is_y_in_data(data, y)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

I have scoured the internet for this error when using DALEX explain, but I have not found any results. Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Comment: sorry I cannot reproduce your error. I think there's some conflicts between packages or your column names are weird. can you do this, DALEX:::is_y_in_data(datax,datax$DV), and see what it returns?

Comment: Otherwise maybe do dput(head(datax,5)) and paste the output, so that we can reproduce the error

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  DALEX:::is_y_in_data(datax,datax$DV) returned NA. Per your suggestion about column names or something being weird, I reproduced the data set and removed all excess columns. Removing the unused columns fixed the problem. Still not sure of the source, but it's fixed. Thank you!